# Broken Images until Page Refresh

Tags: images

SOMETIMES when I visit my blog all the images are broken. Once I refresh the page they appear correctly. This happens on BOTH my tablet and PC and with any browser I try (Chrome, Firefox, IE). I’ve tried clearing the browser cache/cookies and disabling my caching plugin.

I’ve disabled ALL my plugins (yes, every single one) and changed the theme to twenty seventeen. The problem of broken images remains.

Here, I’ve attached [a screenshot](https://thestingyvegan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Screenshot_2018-01-15-10-08-51.png) of what I saw with all plugins disabled on twenty seventeen theme.

I can add that this only happens on one of my two websites, which use the same theme and most of the same plugins and are hosted at the same place. The major difference between the two sites is that the affected one is an addon domain with an SSL certificat and the other is not.

Nor does it happen on any other websites that I visit so I can rule out my internet service provider.

I repeat that this only happens sometimes. I visit my page several times per day and sometimes the images load and sometimes they don’t.

What would cause the images to intermittently load? Where should I check next and what should I ask my host to check?

Comment: Next time it happens I'd suggest inspecting the images to see what URLs they were trying to load from. That should give you a better idea of why they are not loading - URLs are likely wrong. Sounds likely to be an issue with one domain being SSL and the other not. If you're using a CDN, I would disable that and see if it resolves anything. If not, perhaps it's time to add SSL to the non-SSL domain and that way you can 301 redirect any non-https requests. Let's Encrypt will give you a free SSL certificate.

Comment: Have you contacted your host about this? We had a similar issue, turned out they blocked some requests since we use Cloudflare and they sometimes assigned me a blocked IP

Comment: I've tried right clicking on the broken images and they open at the correct URL. I'm not using Cloudflare or any other CDN. I contacted my host but he said he was unable to replicate the problem and suspected it was my browser. However, it doesn't matter which browser or device I use so I'm not convinced that's the problem. It's probably a good idea to add SSL to my primary domain, that could be the fix. Thanks for your suggestions so far and if anyone else has any ideas I welcome them.